# IndexError: list index out of range in"if... else..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

i practice a test of "Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array" in leetcode.Everything is fine but when i test input[1,1] ,it failed with:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

May i know why?(i already got a correct solution but i still wonder this error.)

here is my code:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        index_o=0
        i=1
        while i <len(nums):   
              if nums[index_o]==nums[i]:
                  nums.remove(nums[i])
                  index_o-=1
                  i-=1
                  print("nums[index_o]:",nums[index_o])
                  print("index_o:",index_o)
                  print("nums[i]:",nums[i])
                  print("i:",i)
                  print("nums:",nums)
              else:
                  index_o+=1
                  i+=1
        return len(nums)

n=[1,1]
a=Solution()
print(a.removeDuplicates(n))
print(n)
```

here is the result:

```
f:leetcode>python 190626.py
nums[index_o]: 1
index_o: -1
nums[i]: 1
i: 0
nums: [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "190626.py", line 228, in <module>
    print(a.removeDuplicates(n))
  File "190626.py", line 217, in removeDuplicates
    print("nums[index_o]:",nums[index_o])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

here is a correct solution:

```
class Solution(object):
    def removeDuplicates(self, nums):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        index_o=0
        i=1
        while i <len(nums): 
              if nums[index_o]==nums[i]:
                  nums.remove(nums[index_o])
              else:
                  index_o+=1
                  i+=1
        return len(nums)
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging by printing the variable `i` inside the loop and seeing what it is?

Comment: Well stepping through `n=[1, 1]` you do if `n[0]==n[1]` remove and then set `index_o` to -1, i to 0. I don’t think you intended this. Guessing after this I think n becomes an empty list and so any index is out of range.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variables - it can help to see problem.

Comment: Print index_o before nums[index_o] and also print nums without i to see the whole list as it iterates

Comment: Rather than maintain two indexes use one. Start from index 1 skipping index 0. Use `n.pop(index)` if `n[index-1]==n[index]` and don’t increment index. If they are different increment index. Keep going while `index < len(n)`.

Comment: @AndrewAllen Thank you very much.I know pop() is a better solution but i just wonder why my original code is wrong.(i updated another correct solution)

Comment: No problem, you can now easily improve code by removing `index_o+=1`, `index_o=0` and using `i - 1` for `index_o` in the line `if nums[index_o]==nums[i]:` and pop i instead.

Answer (score 1):

In the third iteration of the loop, you have the variables `i=-1` and n=[]. Your code enters to first `if` as `-1 < 0` equals `True`.*

At this point you try to access your array with the variable `index_o`, which is -2. Because your array is empty, n[-2] returns `IndexError: list index out of range` error.

Some comments on your code:
 - The algorithm does not do what it supposed to do but I can understand your thinking.
 - Why would remove duplicates function would return the length of the output array, and not the array itself ?
 - To test that algorithm, you can use the `set()` built-in, that will remove the duplicates from an array. Then you can compare them.
 - When developing algorithms, always use debugging by printing the values, as advised by @Mark-meyer in the comments.

*I didn't run your algorithm locally and debugged, I just tracked it from head. So some values might be off by one.

Comment: @Toothpick  1.set() built-in can't be use because it require "remove the duplicates in-place ".2.i printed before but array is not empty as following:          ---code:....index_o-=1   i-=1  print("nums[index_o]:",nums[index_o]) print("index_o:",index_o) print("nums[i]:",nums[i])  print("i:",i) 
----output:nums[index_o]: 1
index_o: -1
nums[i]: 1
i: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "190626.py", line 228, in <module>
    print(a.removeDuplicates(n))
  File "190626.py", line 217, in removeDuplicates
    print("nums[index_o]:",nums[index_o])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @CZ_want2b please update your question rather than try to put code in a comment

Answer (score 0):

When the first time arrives to execute the `while` loop and the statement of `if` is true, then the variable `index_o` will take the value -1, the variable `i` will be 0 and the `while` loop will be run again as `i=0 < len(nums)=1`. So the next time, `if` statement will check `if nums[-1] == nums[0]` which is out of index. I suggest you to add an `if` statement just to make sure your array pointers will not get negative values.

Comment: Yes you are right but it will return true as nums[-1] =last_value_of_nums=nums[0] so it will remove both the first and the last value of nums and the while loop will continue to be true so it will continue trying to access elements of an empty list

Comment: ...I know, I posted comment 30 mins ago to that effect. You're preaching to the converted.

Comment: @KostasPapageorge the problem is that program stopped when nums[-1] =nums[0],the list have no chance to remove last value.

Comment: @CZ_want2b the program stopped when you tried to access the nums[index_o] to print it. Which means you tried to access nums[0] which is removed..try to print the len(nums) in each iteration

Comment: @CZ_want2b note your code now fails on the actual print `print("nums[index_o]:",nums[index_o])` because nums is now empty having had last element removed just before trying to print. As Kostas says if you print nums or len(nums) just before this failing print statement you can see this directly